# Winform UI not showing

Tags: c#, winforms, mstest

I have a windows form that is opened from a Unit Test, the unit test is declared with the following attribute

```
[TestMethod]
public void ConnectNotStartedStateAndIsExpiredStatus
```

Internally this is calling a method which does the following

```
fldNavigationEndUrl = url;
             var webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
             webBrowser.Navigated += new WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler(ClaimsWebBrowser_Navigated);
             webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
             webBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
             webBrowser.Navigate(fldNavigationEndUrl);

             DisplayLoginForm = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();
             DisplayLoginForm.SuspendLayout();

             // size the login form
             int dialogWidth = 925;
             int dialogHeight = 525;
             DisplayLoginForm.Width = dialogWidth;
             DisplayLoginForm.Height = dialogHeight;
             DisplayLoginForm.Text = fldNavigationEndUrl;

             DisplayLoginForm.Controls.Add(webBrowser);
             DisplayLoginForm.ResumeLayout(false);
             Application.EnableVisualStyles();
             Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
             Application.Run(DisplayLoginForm);
```

The form in this is firing the navigated event, however the UI is not showing up. Any help here.

Comment: I don't know if you can do UI stuff in normal MSTest tests. I think you have to use a [Coded-UI test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx) if you want the UI to work (but I am not 100% sure)

Comment: @GrantWinney `Application.Run(DisplayLoginForm);` should do a `Show()` internally but I agree, you should not be spawning UI for unit tests.

Comment: The idea in this case is to open a browser and get cookie which is generated which will be used for next calls in authentication. Coded UI in this case is something that is not in the landscape. Is there any other way to get the cookie generated.

Comment: Yes, mock the cookie away... or the code that sets/gets the cookie information.